# Distributed caching framework

Tags: java, caching, distributed-caching

We are trying to develop a system for distributed caching. Right now, we have 12 applications and they all load same cache. So each jvm loads cache in its in-memory. Problem with this system is redundant data. All 12 applications are loading same cache.

We want to develop a system where you add one or two(for failover) JVM's which load cache and the other 12 applications call these new Cache JVM's.

Can someone suggest me if there are any technologies/frameworks that has solution for my needs?

Thanks

Comment: [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) is a distributed hashmap, which actually implements Java's `Map` interface. The data is distributed across nodes in different JVMs and if one JVM process stops, the data hold by this JVM is spread across the other active nodes. It furthermore provides an auto-lookup for nodes and locking mechanism to protect data from being accessed by other nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Memcached](http://www.memcached.org/). It may offer a solution to your distributed cache needs.

Also, as @Guy Bouallet mentioned, [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is also a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ehcache is a good alternative. It can be used to cache data loaded from database, Web pages or other key/value elements in a distributed environment.
I personally used it in several professional applications and it had shown to be an efficent solution.